# Things to consider when designing REST/RPC for mobile networks

Tags: rest, http, mobile, grpc

I am sure that this question might have been asked earlier but I could not find it.

**What are the key things that need to be considered when designing API to communicate with mobile clients using low bandwidth or flaky network connections?**

I feel that if you send binary payload from server then client will have to incur CPU cost to deserialise. Reducing network roundtrip would definitely help.

If someone can link to any research paper or article or book then I would really appreciate.

Comment: ritesh - Does this link help ? https://blog.octo.com/en/api-designs-for-low-connectivity/   I think API's should be built in fashion where they are resilient enough irrespective of whether the network bandwidth is good or bad. Regarding binary payload, if you have the client coding in your control, then you can go for the binary payload option for the right reasons you pointed out, but if you want your API's to be widely adopted and Consumer Centric then may be having JSON and API specs(swagger) with smaller payloads would be preferred.

Comment: @Rohan Thanks for sharing the link. It helps in understanding the importance of retries and different failure states with low network connectivity. I feel that there might be more corner cases like this. I am not able to find 1 comprehensive answer which work in majority of the cases.

Comment: ritesh - Do you do both in your enterprise... RPC and REST ?  OR either of it. OR do you do REST and now thinking to see if RPC is better ? Is there a need to manage the API's you create in your enterprise. Do you have developers who want to go on a single portal and get a list and try out these API's created ?

Comment: @Rohan Just to clarify, I did not ask this question with some project in mind. It has no relation to my current work. I mentioned RPC to make it bit generic and cover more cases. REST is not the right fit for all the user cases.

Comment: You already linked the gRPC tag in your question. Please use that. I have build +- 6 apps for clients using this technology and its incredible. Flaky connections and low bandwidth is laughed at by gRPC. CPU cost for deserialization is negligible. Remember even JSON is a form of serialization so either way, It will be the same. If CPU starts to be an issue you can disable compression but I doubt you will ever have an issue with that.

Comment: You might consider asking this in the SoftwareEngineering community (switch on the top right corner).